# How to get the data of guest from magento database?

Tags: database, magento

I tried to download the customer data and was able to download only the data of logged in users. 
Wanted to know is there a way to download the data of all customers who has purchased from my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to browse the orders `sales_flat_order` where the attribute `customer_is_guest = 1`. In the order table you are already able to get fields like `customer_email, customer_firstname, customer_lastname`...

You will find the billing/shipping addresses in `sales_flat_order_address`.

Orders and addresses can be joined this way:

`sales_flat_order.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id`